# what does this block of vba code mean?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Function calcamountpastdueDEV(ByVal creditstatus As String, ByVal user21 As Double, ByVal payoff As Double, ByVal nextdue As Date, ByVal currentdue As Double, ByVal finaldue As Date, _
ByVal payment As Double, ByVal endofdatadate As Date, ByVal principal As Double, ByVal princ_pd As Double, ByVal lfeedue As Double, ByVal prpaydown As Double, ByVal trkstatus As String, ByVal trkacct As String) As Double

' Calculate Amount Past Due
' See comments on each statement

' If it does not meet any of the criteria,
' then set to "-1000" to generate an error.
Dim amountpastdue As Double

amountpastdue = -1000

trkstatus = Trim(trkstatus)
trkacct = Trim(trkacct)

' If these are closed accounts or current account (11) then set to 0.
' CREDIT STATUS comes from the CreditCalculations query.
If creditstatus = 5 Or creditstatus = 11 Or creditstatus = 13 Or creditstatus = 61 Or creditstatus = 62 Or creditstatus = 63 Or creditstatus = 64 Then

    amountpastdue = 0
    GoTo RoundAmountPastDue

End If

' IF Deficiency Balance is greater than 0,
' then use Deficiency Balance.
If user21 > 0 Then

    amountpastdue = user21
    GoTo RoundAmountPastDue

End If

' IF assigned to collections or involuntary repo or charge off,
' then there should be a deficiency balance and we should not have gotten here so
' produce error code -999 for further investigation.
If creditstatus = 95 Or creditstatus = 96 Or creditstatus = 97 Then

    amountpastdue = -999
    GoTo RoundAmountPastDue

End If

' If Credit Status 93 (Account assigned to internal or external collections)
' produce error code -998 for further investigation because we don't want to use this code.
If creditstatus = 93 Then

    amountpastdue = -998
    GoTo RoundAmountPastDue

End If
```

Comment: Well, it says `' Calculate Amount Past Due ' See comments on each statement`

Comment: Thank you , what i am really trying to find out is why is amountpastdue=-1000 at beginning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has shown no attempt at understanding his own very simple question.

Comment: See what Johnny posted below...

Comment: This statement sets it to -1000 `amountpastdue = -1000`, then a whole lot of `IF....END IF` statements execute in turn to see if the figure should change.  It starts at -1000, then if credit status is equal to 5, 11, .. etc it gets changed to 0 and then the code jumps to RoundAmountPastDue.  If the credit status isn't equal to those figures it goes on to check user21 value, and so on....

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on the comment

```
' If it does not meet any of the criteria,
' then set to "-1000" to generate an error.
```

The function is designed so that the return value is either the actual **calculated value** (if >= 0), or an **error code** (if < 0).

It would be called like this:

```
x = calcamountpastdueDEV(...)
If x >= 0 Then
    ' do something with the value
Else
    ' handle error code x
End If
```